# compare the product of two sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let $a_j$ and $b_j$ be real sequences such that $0\leq a_j, b_j \leq 1$ and there exists a unique threshold such as $j^*$ such that:
\begin{equation}
a_j - b_j = \begin{cases}
             <0  & \text{if } j \le j^* \\
             >0  & \text{if } j > j^*
       \end{cases} \quad
\end{equation}
Now, for $i \geq 1$ let $a'_i=\Pi_{j=0}^{i-1} a_j$ and $b'_i=\Pi_{j=0}^{i-1} b_j$ .

I was wondering whether there exists a unique $i^*$, such that:

\begin{equation}
a'_i - b'_i = \begin{cases}
             <0  & \text{if } i \leq i^* \\
             >0  & \text{if } i > i^*
       \end{cases} \quad
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

As written the statement is not true because of the fact that $$a'_0 = b'_0 = 1,$$ by definition of the empty product (assuming that the sequences are indexed from $0$), which makes the statement instantly false. Assuming this is a mistake, and redefining $$a'_i = \prod_{j=0}^{i} a_j \text{ and } b'_i = \prod_{j=0}^{i} b_j,$$ the statement is still unfortunately false; if we for instance define
\begin{align*}
a_i &= \frac{1+\min(i,1)}{3} \\
b_i &= \frac{2-\min(i,1)}{3},
\end{align*}
then clearly $a'_1 = b'_1 = \frac 2 9$, so the condition is not satisfied.

However, liberally assuming that the $< 0$ is meant to be $\leq 0$ (and using the redefinition), the statement is in fact true. All we have to prove is that $$a'_i - b'_i \leq 0 \implies a'_{i+1} - b'_{i+1} \leq 0;$$ it is easy to see that this implies the result. We note that since $0 < a_j, b_j < 1$ then $$a_j - b_j < 0 \iff \frac{a_j}{b_j} < 1$$ (and similar for $a_j - b_j > 0$). We also have $0 < a'_i, b'_i < 1$ (for $i > 0$), so the same is true. Now, note that $$\frac{a'_{i+1}}{b'_{i+1}} = \frac{a'_i}{b'_i} \frac{a_{i+1}}{b_{i+1}}.$$ Are you able to finish the problem from here? (Hint: $i^* \geq j^*$.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I made some clarifications and also made some revisions to some typo regarding the direction of inequalities. Is your answer still valid?

Comment: Hi, sorry if this wasn't quite clear in my answer: one of the issues is that $a'_i - b'_i$ is not allowed to be $0$ anywhere. If you replace the $< 0$ in the constraint on $a'_i - b'_i$ with a $\leq 0$, then it works. However, if $a_i, b_i$ are allowed to be equal to $0$ or $1$, that introduces a few extra cases; you can probably figure these out yourself though, because that will cause all the terms of the corresponding sequence from $a'_i, b'_i$ to be $0$ eventually.

Comment: Seems clear now, Thanks!